# what is a spectrum of an Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, synthetic-differential-geometry

In this lectures [Fields](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/newideaofquantumfieldtheory-fields/) the author defines

> An $\underline{\text { infinitesimally thickened point }}$ $$
>  \mathbb{D}:=\operatorname{Spec}(A) $$ is represented by a commutative
> algebra $A \in \mathbb{R A l g}$ which as a real vector space is a
> direct sum $$ A \simeq_{\mathbb{R}}\langle 1\rangle \oplus V $$ of the
> 1 -dimensional space $\langle 1\rangle=\mathbb{R}$ of multiples of 1
> with a finite dimensional vector space $V$ that is a nilpotent ideal
> in that for each element $a \in V$ there exists a natural number $n
> > \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ a^{n+1}=0 $$

My question is what is $Spec(A)$?

Answer (score 1):

${\rm Spec}(A)$, read "the spectrum of $A$", is the set of all prime ideals of $A$.

Comment: $A$ is an algebra not a ring.

Comment: If $A$ is an $\Bbb R$-algebra, then it is also a ring - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380177/what-is-the-difference-between-a-ring-and-an-algebra).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde so you are saying  that $Spec(A)$ is the spectrum of $A$ when we treat $A$ as a ring?

Comment: The notation ${\rm Spec}(A)$ refers to the set of prime ideals in a ring $A$, yes.